# Drupal7 Apachesolr search with Facet Api and Display Suites facets configuration

Tags: solr, configuration, drupal-7, faceted-search, display-suite

Does anybody know, how I can get all my taxonomy_term_references for my video content type to be listed as Facet options on the Configuration > Apache Solr search > Facets tab (admin/config/search/apachesolr/settings/solr/facets)? I am trying to fix the search on an existing Drupal site that wasn't built by me and I can only see one taxonomy_term_reference for one vocabulary, but not all of them. The site uses Display Suite as well.

Here is a screenshot of my Facet tab:
[Screenshot of facets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbTPY.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think I sold this myself. But wow, why isn't there any documentation for this.

A couple of configuration need to be set:

1. Structure > Display Suite > [Taxonomy term] > Manage Display >
   Default tab (top tab) > Custom Display Settings (bottom tab) :
   Select "Search Result"
2. Structure > Taxonomy > [Vocabulary name] >
   Manage display (tab) >Search Result : Full Term Name -> Format:
   "Plain text"
3. Structure > Content types > [Content type with taxonomy
   term reference field] > Search index: [Vocabulary] -> Region:
   Content
4. Configuration >  Development > Performance > Clear all
   caches Configuration > Search and metadata > Apache Solr search >
   Settings > Facets: Select Facet for the Taxonomy/Vocabulary
5. Configuration > Search and metadata > Apache Solr search > Settings > Facets > Click configure display: Hard limit -> No limit (not sure why that was necessary, but it was)

Screenshots:

[Enable search results (Step 1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuFbz.png)

[Add taxonomy to search results (Step 2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gY9OI.png)

[Select facet (Step 4)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hnjam.png)

[Facet configuration (Step 5)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwfVH.png)